# I need add new event object with "dayClick" in fullcalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

I need to know how to add a new event with "dayClick" to the calendar because I am going to use it to manage my holidays.I'm using java + javascript to develop the application. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The dayClick documentation is here: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/mouse/dayClick/

What you do on that event is entirely up to you and how you want to implement creating a new event.  You could do like Google Calendar and open a dialog asking for event details, you could navigate to a new form to gather the information.  Really, just up to you.